# how to add jpg image to IOs project for Visual studio with xamarin

Tags: image, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I got a problem in my project in Visual studio with Xamarin. I want to add a .jpg image to images sets in IOS project's asset catalog. But VS allow me add only .png files. Is there any way to add .jpg image to use it in storyboard and in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add them under the folder `Resources`. Detail Refer [Working With Resources](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_resources/)
[image]

## Usage:

**In Code**

```
image.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("test.jpg");
```

**In Storyboard**
[image]

Comment: Thank you. And what about using images from "Resources" in designer of storyboard, not in code?

Comment: Emm. Is it possible nonimgur server? It's blocked in my region.

Comment: Image in your post placed in imgur.com. And imgur.com is blocked in my region. So I can't see image

Comment: @AdeptusMechanicus just click on the imageview ,find the image in property menu , fill it with test.jpg

Comment: Ok, understood. Thank you again.